# Large files wont upload

Tags: php, mysql, video, upload

This is the code for my uploading system, it uploads a file and enters info into mysql,small files work fine but large files dont appear in the ftp, they do make a mysql entry but the entry is empty

```
<?php
$count = 0;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name) {
        if (strlen($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]) > 1) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], 'upload/'.$name)) {
                $count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<?php
$link = mysql_connect('server', 'user', 'pass'); 
if (!$link) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db(database);

$title = $_POST['title'];
$path= $name;
$description = $_POST['description'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `videos` ( `id` , `title` , `path` , `description` )
VALUES (
NULL , '$title', '$path', '$description'
);";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if(! $result )
{
 die('Could not update database: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Uploaded successfully\n";
mysql_close();
?>
```

the Page

```
<body>
    <div class="wrap">

<form action="upload_script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
          <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">



                <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple directory="" webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory="">



<INPUT TYPE = "Text" VALUE ="title" NAME = "title">
<textarea name="description">descrtiption</textarea>
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="Upload" />
      </form> 

    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Turn your errors on, do you see any? Probably to do with max upload size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> at Netfirms  the PHP_Upload limit is set by default to 20MB!

Try adding the following to your .htaccess if creating a php.ini with similar correpsonding values doesn't work:

```
 php_value post_max_size 100M
 php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
 php_value memory_limit 64M
```

No guarantees that they'll be a magic fix; but, it's another way to inject php settings. Use the last one only if you're having timeout issues migrating from G1 - otherwise, on shared hosting, it's not exactly smiled upon.

Comment: this is my .htaccess where do i put the code?
Options +FollowSymLinks


<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+?)\/?$ $1.php [NC,L] 
</IfModule>

Answer (score 2):

You should check your php.ini for `upload_max_filesize`.
Also do you see any errors ?

Not enough reputation to comment, sorry.

Edit : If you're hosted by a hosting solution then you should not be able to modify this parameter.

Comment: i dont have a php.ini
i use netfirms for hosting, is it somewhere in control panel?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely limited upload sizes, and since your code simply assumes that nothing could possibly EVER fail, you never see the error message that PHP could be showing you.

At bare minimum, you should have something like

```
if ($_FILES['name']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['name']['error']);
}
```

Since you're apparently doing multi-file upload, you'll have to mod this to handle that, but you NEED something like this.

The error codes are defined here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Your database code is also vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and your actual upload move code is opening up your server to a COMPLETE remote compromise. In short, you are basically hanging a "kick me" sign on your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a php.ini in the same folder where script runs and add following lines:

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
memory_limit = 64M
max_input_time = 0
```

The max_input_time value of 0 means no timeout during upload.

Ideally you would want to copy the original php.ini from system and put in the root and recursively apply that file to apply same setting through the website.

To set a php.ini recursively you will have to set environment variable (setenv) in your sever through .htaccess file.

Comment: Some hosting company will provide you will php.ini file that you can modify with default settings.